# promise.then( ) doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm learning promise about ecma6,I want to get the json data by promise.then(),but it doesn't work by the callback of resolve.I test in chrome under version 44.
the result is [image]

```html
    <button type="button" id="get">get</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ele = document.getElementById('get');
        ele.addEventListener('click', testPromise, false);
        var getData = function (url) {
            var promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', url);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
                xhr.send();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
                xhr.responseType = 'json';
                function handler () {
                    console.log('status: ' + this.status);
                    if (this.status === 200) {
                        console.log(this.response);
                        resolve(this.response);
                    } else {
                        reject(new Error(this.statusText));
                    }
                }
            });
            return promise1;
        }

        function testPromise() {
            getData('http://1.frontendlife.sinaapp.com/test/promise.json').then(function (json) {
                console.log(json);
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: `resolve` is not being called because it is being rejected( Cross-Origin Request Blocked ), the promise works just fine.

Comment: but it under the same origin,why?

Comment: for us, it is cross-origin... what status do you get?

Comment: Id' suggest you do `xhr.send()` AFTER you set the other `xhr` properties.  Not sure if that causes a problem, but it looks like it could cause a problem the way it is.

Comment: @mido22 access http://1.frontendlife.sinaapp.com/test/testPromise.html

Comment: you are getting an error in `ele.attachEvent('onclick', testPromise);`, you have commented the line that works!

Comment: @jperelli I know,I want to test in IE,the problem is not the event listener,you can try in chrome.

Comment: @jfriend00 I set the other xhr properties before xhr.send( ),but it doesn't work sadly.

Comment: @doudou - IE does not yet support `Promise` in any version yet (the new Edge browser in Windows 10 does support it).  You would have to use a third party library like Bluebird or Q for promises in IE.  FYI, your linked page seems to work fine for me in Chrome 44.

Comment: @jfriend00 In chrome's console,what does the line 37 code output?null/Object?my result image is attached in my question,you can see it.

Comment: @doudou - I looked into that and offer a fix in my answer below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I promisify native XHR?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30008114/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a logic error in you xhr handler.  You cannot examine the result of your XHR call until `readyState === 4`.  You have one version in your question and a slightly different version in your linked page, but both can resolve or reject before `readyState === 4` which gives you incomplete results.

Change it to this:

```
   <button type="button" id="get">get</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ele = document.getElementById('get');
        ele.addEventListener('click', testPromise, false);
        var getData = function (url) {
            var promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', url);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
                xhr.send();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
                xhr.responseType = 'json';
                function handler () {
                    if (this.readyState === 4) {
                        console.log('status: ' + this.status);
                        if (this.status === 200) {
                            console.log(this.response);
                            resolve(this.response);
                        } else {
                            reject(new Error(this.statusText));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return promise1;
        }

        function testPromise() {
            getData('http://1.frontendlife.sinaapp.com/test/promise.json').then(function (json) {
                console.log(json);
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot.I got it.btw,the status property about send is readyState.