# Is this a good use case for using Promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm working with a string of XMLHttpRequests that each depend on the one prior to it. Psuedocode:

```
xhr1.open('GET', 'http://foo.com');
xhr1.onload = function(e){
  xhr2.open('POST', xhr1.response.url)
  xhr2.onload = function(e){
    xhr3.open('GET', xhr2.response.url2);
    xhr3.onload = function(e){
      console.log('hooray! you have data from the 3rd URL!');
    }
    xhr3.send();
  }
  xhr2.send();
}
xhr1.send();
```

Is this the kind of situation where using promises would be a good idea to avoid all the callback muck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitively. Assuming a helper function like those from [How do I promisify native XHR?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30008114/1048572), your code could be transformed into

```
makeRequest('GET', 'http://foo.com').then(function(response1) {
    return makeRequest('POST', response1.url);
}).then(function(response2) {
    return makeRequest('GET', response2.url2);
}).then(function(response3) {
    console.log('hooray! you have data from the 3rd URL!');
});
```

Still [callbacks of course](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572), but [no more nesting required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572). Also you'd have simple error handling, and the code looks much cleaner (partially contributed to by the non-promise-related fact of abstracting XHR in its own function).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you return a promise in a `then`, the next chained then listens for that promise instead of resolving from the original promise. Given that `ajaxCall` returns a promise, your code will then look like:

```
ajaxCall(1)
.then(function(result1){
  return ajaxCall(2);
})
.then(function(result2){
  return ajaxCall(3);
})
.then(function(result3){
  // all done
});

// Sample AJAX call
function ajaxCall(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    // xhr code. call resolve/reject with accordingly
    // args passed into resolve/reject will be passed as result in then
  });
}
```