# Javascript promises not working in my case

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

Its a simple case

```
var q = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve(initRequest('get', 'includes/getRemessaRegistrada.php', null, remessasList));
    }).then(function(){
        console.log('ok');
    });
```

I'm learning javascript promises concept. Why console.log('ok') is coming before resolve processing?

Comment: What is `initRequest`?

Comment: Take this like some assynchronous function.

Comment: What does it return? If it returns a promise, you don't have to wrap it using `new Promise()`. If it doesn't return a promise (but uses callbacks, for instance), your code won't work as expected.

Comment: I dont know if I've expressed my wish, my english its bad so much. But here is my code: http://pastebin.com/hyszfXww

Comment: Essentially, you want to promisify `XMLHttpRequest`, which has been asked and answered [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008114/how-do-i-promisify-native-xhr).

Comment: Thanks, @robertklep, the example you showed me worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

In your code `initRequest()` does not return anything.  For your code to work as you have it, `initRequest()` must return a promise that is tied to the underlying asynchronous operation.  And, if it did return a promise, then you don't need another wrapping promise around that.

**Promises by themselves do not have magical powers to somehow know when an underlying asynchronous operation completes.**  They just don't have such powers.  A promise only works when there's an asynchronous operation that calls resolve or reject on the promise at the appropriate time when the asynchronous operation completes with a value or an error.  The promise then serves as an easier to use interface for managing and coordinating asynchronous results or errors.

You are running `initRequest()` which starts your async operation and then immediately returns, then long before it finishes, you are calling `resolve(undefined)` for your wrapping promise.  This promise will resolve long before `initRequest()` is done and will not know anything about the async return value.

The best solution here would be to get or use a promisified version of XMLHttpRequest so you can make ajax calls with functions that just return promises.  jQuery has one built in.  The latest browsers have `fetch()` which does Ajax and returns a promise and there are dozens of small libraries available to do this or you could make your own.  If you aren't already using a library that has this built in (like jQuery) and you need to get something specifically for this, I'd probably get a `fetch()` polyfill since this is clearly the future direction for browsers.

If you wanted just a simple XHR wrapper or a way to make ajax calls using a promise interface, here are some ways to go:

[How do I promisify native XHR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008114/how-do-i-promisify-native-xhr)

[XR](https://github.com/radiosilence/xr)

[Fetch Polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch)

---

It also occurs to me that because you have `return req.responseText` in your `initRequest()` function, you may think that `initRequest()` is returning that value.  It is not.  `initRequest()` returns nothing.  `return req.responseText` is being returned to an async callback which just goes into the bowels of the XMLHttpRequest implementation.  Your `initRequest()` function has long, long since already returned and returned `undefined`.  For more on why this is the case, see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).