# Equivalent of jQuery ajaxStart in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular

I want to know if there is an equivalent of ajaxStart or ajaxStop in Angular 2.

I want to check if there's an ajax which runs into the document.

According the **[official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)** of ajaxStart, it will be triggered when there is any Ajax Request. And I want something like this in Angular 2.

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( "#loading" ).show();
});
```

I do this:

- into my `app.component.ts`, I show my loader
- when my ajax is success, I hide my loader

But, some of my page doesn't have ajax call, so if I show my loader using my `app.component.ts`, it will be impossible to hide this, because, none of ajax request is present into this page.

I think, if I listen if ajax is not present into my page, if will hide my loader.

I use `localStorage` to save the status of ajax.
If the page has ajax, I set a value to that xhr
Otherwise, I remove the status stored into `localStorage`.
Each time, the user arrive in the page. My script check, if there is an ajax running into that page.

**app.component.ts**

```
if(localStorage.getITem("xhr")) {
    // action here
}
```

**request.service.ts**

```
...
let checkForAjax: any = {
    setXhr () {
        localStorage.setItem("xhr", "1");
    },
    removeXhr () {
        localStorage.removeItem("xhr");
    }
}
...
```

into get request, I do this (before success callback):

```
checkForAjax.setXhr()
```

And into callback of get request, I just remove the status.

```
checkForAjax.removeXhr()
```

By the way, I haven't the `xhr` status, after my ajax is successed. So If I check it into my `app.component.ts`, I just test if there's a property `xhr`into my `localStorage`.

I work now, but I want another way to listen for ajax with angular 2.

Is that way exist?
How can it will be done?

Comment: check the interceptor in angular js, i think that will solve your problem.
you can refer this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143194/progress-bar-loader-with-angularjs

Comment: It is angular 1. Is the principe the same?
In this link, there'sn't solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of Promises

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30008115/3152269 explains it better than i ever could, but it seems right up your alley

What i generally do when i shoot off an ajax request is to make a promise to run some code after it receives a response.

This makes Ajax calls easier to read and ensures the code doesn't run unless you want it to.