# Load a modal dialog with ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter php (MVC framework) and I want to open a modal dialog when clicked a button, but my problem is that my modal appears only in my response network(in preview) and not on my actual screen.

This is my modal.php file on view side.

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my controller to point to that view:

```
 public function showmachinelist() {
        $this->load->view('monitor/modal');

    }
```

And I have this button in js to trigger my ajax:

```
button_2: "<button type=\"button\" class=\"getid btn btn-default tara\" data-target=\"#myModal\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-id=\""+ missedEntry.id +"\" >Select</button>"
```

And this ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Monitor/showmachinelist",
    data: {'val' : imagename},
    dataType: "text"
    }).done(function(data) {
   console.log("test2");
   }).fail(function() {
alert( "error" );
});
```

How I can make show that modal?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ajax` returns you some html, you have to put that html into a `div` and make that `div` a `popup` or `modal` or `dialog`. 
For this you can use `Bootstrap Modal`, `Jquery UI Dialog` etc.

[Bootstrap Modal](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

[Jquery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
[How do I promisify native XHR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008114/how-do-i-promisify-native-xhr)

Which this function can centralise all your AJAX requests, your .htaccess call the file (controller) and this call the model. The result, maybe a text information or groups of data (transform it to JSON format) will use to show in page or to move to new page, etc.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31837199)