# Using Ajax data inside Vue Component

Tags: ajax, components, vuejs2

I built some functionality which when I tried to export it to a vue component it stopped working.

I am almost certain it has to do with the ajax not being available when the component renders the template as the array is empty inside the template.

Can anyone see any way to delay the render until the ajax has loaded?

Maybe I am barking up the wrong tree. The data is available in the ajax .done() callback.

```
<template>

      <div   v-for="item in filteredItems"  @mouseover="activate" @mouseout="deactivate" @click="openlink"  class="item" :data-link="item.link">
      <div class="vline"></div>
        <div class="details">
          <div class="top">
            <div class="media">{{item.sectors}}</div>
            <div class="title">{{item.title}}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="description">{{item.description}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="img">
                  <div class="overlay"><a class="button" v-bind:href="'featured/'+item.link">View project <span class="plus"><span>[</span><span>+</span><span>]</span></span></a></div>
                  <div v-if="context == 'home'">
                     <img class="workimg" v-bind:src="item.imagemobile">
                  </div>
                  <div v-else>
                     <img class="workimg" v-bind:src="item.imagemobile">
                  </div>


                </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</template>

  <script>
export default {
   props: ['context'],
    data() {
            return {
            work: [],
            }

  },


             computed: {

  filteredItems: function () {
    if (this.context == 'home') {
    return this.work.filter(function (works) {  return works});
  }
  else {
      return this.work.filter(function (works) {  return works});
  }
  },




},
  mounted() {

    self= this;
     $.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/work.json",
})
.done(function(data){
    self.work = data;
   console.log(self.work);
 // work has data!

  })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
       console.log(error)
    });

  }

    }


</script>
```

---

Edit:

It must have been the use of the this/self in the ajax function as the arrow syntax gets it working, this is strange because this look correct.

```
$.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/work.json'
      })
      .done(data => {

        this.work = data;

      })
      .fail((xhr, status, error) => {

      })
```

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: The template is not rendering because there is no data.

Comment: The template should render when the data is retrieved. Is that the first line of your template? The div with v-for?

Comment: Hi Bert, tried this but that is not it because   console.log( this.work); inside the computed "filteredItems" is empty.

Comment: That's true, it will be empty *initially*. And when your Ajax completes it will be called again.

Comment: Thanks for your help  Bert please look at the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classic way to hide the render until a request is done is to add a `isLoading` property to your `data`. Notice that I'm using [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) so I have access to the right context.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-if="failed">Request failed</p>
    <p v-else-if="isLoading">Loading...</p>
    <div v-else>
      <!-- your content here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      failed: false,
      work: []
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    this.isLoading = true
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/work.json'
    })
    .done(data => {
      this.isLoading = false
      this.work = data
    })
    .fail((xhr, status, error) => {
      this.loading = false
      this.failed = true
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

But, several questions:

- how did you register jquery in your app?
- did you think about using pure XMLHttpRequest? Or even better [with promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008114/how-do-i-promisify-native-xhr)?
- did you think about using [vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource)?

Comment: Thanks George, I am adding jquery in my man app var $ = require('jquery');

Comment: I will look into vue-resource

Comment: @LeBlaireau There's no reason to switch to vue-resource if you're comfortable with jquery for Ajax. Yes you are already using promises.

Comment: will mark this up as it got me partially to the solution! :) I did not need the is.loading but the arrow syntax did it.