# ajax variable is undefined only for the first time in cordova

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

well, this is the problem: the variable day is undefined for the first time that setDates() function works. Then the next time it returns the value that the day variable should have the last time. The variable is defined until to reach in the setDates.php file. Then for some a reason it is undefined for the first time. Php file is nothing important, just a die(variable) function... Please help me.

```
function controlDates() {

//today = $('#chooseDate').val();
today= document.getElementById('chooseDate').value;
user = localStorage.Username;
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        msg = this.responseText;
        $('#comfirmMess').html(msg);
        if (msg == 'available') {
            $('#comfirmMess').html('');
            $('#ChooseHour').show();
            $('#checkButton').show();
            setDates();
        }
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://ptyxiaki.000webhostapp.com/controlDates.php?today=" + today + '&user=' + user, true);
xhttp.send();

}


function setDates() {
if ($("input:radio[name='ProgramName']").is(":checked"))
    trainName = $("input[name='ProgramName']:checked").val();
 //today = $('#chooseDate').val();
var dsplit = today.split("/");
// day = new Date(dsplit[0], dsplit[1] - 1, dsplit[2]);
day = new Date(today);
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "Sunday";
weekday[1] = "Monday";
weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
weekday[4] = "Thursday";
weekday[5] = "Friday";
weekday[6] = "Saturday";

day = weekday[day.getDay()];

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        msg = this.responseText;
        mess=msg;
        msgarr = msg.split(" ");
        startTime = msgarr[0];
        finnishTime = msgarr[1];


    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://ptyxiaki.000webhostapp.com/setDates.php?today="    + day, true);
xhttp.send();




var xhttl = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttl.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        msg = this.responseText;
        if (msg == 'Please enter a valid trainer') {
            $('#comfirmMess').html(msg);
            $('#ChooseHour').hide();
            $('#checkButton').hide();
        }
        res = [];
        DisHours = msg.split(" ");
        for (i = 0; i < DisHours.length - 1; i++) {
            res[i] = DisHours[i].split(":");
            DisHours[i] = res[i][0];
        }
    }
}

xhttl.open("GET", "https://ptyxiaki.000webhostapp.com/showAvailDates.php?date=" + today + '&trainName=' + trainName, true);
xhttl.send();


}
```

Comment: I don't see declaration of `day`

Comment: ^ It's declared twice.

Comment: possibly.. this (day) should be out of the function body

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that AJAX requests are **asyncrononous**; your call to `setDates` isn't waiting on your response to your call to `controlDates`. As such, the flow of your logic is like this:

1. You make a request to `controlDates`
2. The request has been successfully **sent** to `controlDates`
3. You make a request to `setDates` with an undefined `day`
4. The request has been successfully **sent** to `setDates`
5. At some random point, the response from the call to `controlDates` comes back 
   (presumably successfully), and `day` gets defined.

As such, your first call to `setDates` is still waiting for `day` to be defined by the success response from the call to `controlDates`.

To get around this, you're looking to make use of a [**promise**](https://davidwalsh.name/write-javascript-promises) and say that 'something is going to come back from call A, wait until it gets here to make call B'.

To make use of a promise with a raw XMLHttpRequest, you can use the following (credited to [**SomeKittens**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30008115/2341603)):

```
function makeRequest (method, url) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject({
          status: this.status,
          statusText: xhr.statusText
        });
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function () {
      reject({
        status: this.status,
        statusText: xhr.statusText
      });
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
}

makeRequest('GET', 'http://example.com')
.then(function (datums) {
  console.log(datums);
})
.catch(function (err) {
  console.error('Augh, there was an error!', err.statusText);
});
```

Hope this helps! :)