# Executing a function in backgroud/seperate thread in angular 2 application

Tags: angular, web-worker

I am developing an application and I have below requirement. from my angular application I am making REST call to server which will trigger some job on the server and return status as "Job Started". After that I want to keep checking status of job every 10 seconds, for which server provides API that return status of job.

Now my requirement is I need to call this job status API every 10 seconds, but in background, that means user should able to perform other tasks on application.

How would I achieve this?

Any help with some example would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve this by 2 way.

#### Simplest way - `setInterval()`.

Since it's only check if job is done via `http` request it won't kill `UI` and user will be able to perform other actions.

```
setInterval(() => {
   this.http.post(...).subscribe(
      (res) => handleResponse(res);
   );
}, 10000);
```

#### Web Worker

With web workers there is a lot of trouble, depends how your project is build etc. However it will do the trick with background thread but there is a question. Is it only to make a http request to check some data is necessary for web worker?. If yes, then look at this [link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) it's well explained how it works. You will have to create `XHR` request since `Angular` and `jQuery`(I'm not 100% sure, but maybe there is `ajax` for web workers) won't work there. The biggest trouble would be loading source code of web worker. You can `stringify` source code of web worker ([how to](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-inlineworkers)) or just build it as file and link it. It's depends how your project is gonna be build in production.

```
// source code for worker.
let code = function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        makeRequest()
        .then(function(res) {
            // process request. if you want to send message to main thread just use fn below
            // message can be almost everything, but it can not pass any methods.
            // self is simply worker. you don't have to declar self, it's already declared like window in main thread.
            self.postMessage(message)
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            // process request failure.
        })
    }, 10000)
};

// stringify source code and make it blob as described in link

let worker = new Worker(code);

worker.addEventListener('message', function(workerReponse) {
    // workerReponse is simply `message` which was passed in self.postMessage(message).
})
```

[Source code to blob file](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-inlineworkers)

makeRequest method can look like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30008115/4700863)

Answer (score 3):

You can use RxJS observable with timer so that you control the timer with ease. If you don't destroy the timer on page unload, API will be called after page destroy also. In the component file API will be called for every 10 seconds till the variable alive is true and we are setting that to false on destroy to stop the timer.

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interval-observable-demo)

Component file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppTestService } from './app-test.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers:[ AppTestService ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  alive = true;

  constructor(private appTest : AppTestService) {
    Observable.timer(0,10000)
    .takeWhile(() => this.alive) // only fires when component is alive
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.appTest.getData().subscribe(data=> {
        console.log(data);
      })
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.alive = false; // switches your IntervalObservable off
  }
}
```

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AppTestService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getData(){
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1');
  }

}
```