# Get status code from any website

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to ensure that a url sent to my server is an actual website (**heroku app**) rather than validating for `htp://fooxbvgf5766.herokuapp.com`. A status code of 200 would tell me that url is an actual website.

Been searching and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008114/how-do-i-promisify-native-xhr).

```
checkValidWebsite(appName) {
    const url = `https://${appName}.herokuapp.com`
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
          resolve(xhr.response);
        } else {
          reject({
            status: this.status,
            statusText: xhr.statusText
          });
        }
      };
      xhr.onerror = function () {
        reject({
          status: this.status,
          statusText: xhr.statusText
        });
      };
      xhr.send();
    });
  }
```

**Running the function:**

```
checkValidWebsite('foo')
.then(resp => {
  console.log(resp)
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log('Error:', e)
})
```

Checking for `https://foo.herokuapp.com` I get cors errors. Is there a way to detect that a url is an actual website?

Comment: not with clientside JavaScript becuase of CORS

Comment: You can use the JSONP way though

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: So basically, move this logic on my server?

Comment: `curl -I https://whatever.herokuapp.com` gives me a 200 then 404 status codes for dud sub-domains, but 200 then 502 for good ones. Does this suffice?

Comment: @KenY-N That would work. Nothing crazy I'm after. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @epascarello actually it's because of Same Origin Policy

Comment: @Devesh - JSONP is not a way to bypass CORS, because you can't bypass CORS