# Which versions of npm came with which versions of node?

Tags: node.js, npm

Which versions of npm came with which versions of node? I can't find such a list.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

At https://nodejs.org/dist/ there is [index.json](https://nodejs.org/dist/index.json) which indicates each version of nodejs and which version of npm is bundled with it.

---

**index.json**

An excerpt from one of the objects in the array of `index.json` reads:

```json
[
  {
    "version": "v10.6.0",       //<--- nodejs version
    "date": "2018-07-04",
    "files": [
      ...
    ],
    "npm": "6.1.0",             //<--- npm version
    "v8": "6.7.288.46",
    "uv": "",
    "zlib": "1.2.11",
    "openssl": "1.1.0h",
    "modules": "64",
    "lts": false
  },
  ...
]
```

Whereby each object in the array has a `version` *(i.e. the nodejs version)* and `npm` *(i.e. the npm version)* key/value pair.

---

### Programmatically obtaining the versions

#### In-browser Snippet

```js
(async function logVersionInfo() {
  try {
    const json = await requestVersionInfo();
    const versionInfo = extractVersionInfo(json);
    createVersionTable(versionInfo);
  }
  catch ({ message }) {
    console.error(message);
  }
})();

// Promise-wrapped XHR from @SomeKittens' answer: 
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/30008115
function requestVersionInfo() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://nodejs.org/dist/index.json');
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject({
          status: this.status,
          statusText: xhr.statusText
        });
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      reject({
        status: this.status,
        statusText: xhr.statusText
      });
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
}

function extractVersionInfo(json) {
  return JSON.parse(json).map(({ version, npm = '-' }) => 
    ({ nodejs: version.replace(/^v/, ''), npm })
  );
}

function createVersionTable(array) {
  const table = document.createElement("table");
  table.border = 1;

  const headerRow = document.createElement('tr');

  for (const headerText of Object.keys(array[0])) {
    const headerCell = document.createElement('th');
    headerCell.textContent = headerText;
    headerRow.appendChild(headerCell);
  }

  table.appendChild(headerRow);

  for (const el of array) {
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");

    for (const value of Object.values(el)) {
      const td = document.createElement("td");
      td.textContent = value;
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }

    table.appendChild(tr);
  }

  document.body.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
td { padding: 0 0.4rem; } tr:nth-child(even) td { background-color: antiquewhite; }
```

#### Node.js Script

Consider utilizing the following node.js script to request the data from the `https://nodejs.org/dist/index.json` endpoint.

**get-versions.js**

```js
const { get } = require('https');

const ENDPOINT = 'https://nodejs.org/dist/index.json';

function requestVersionInfo(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    get(url, response => {
      let data = '';
      response.on('data', chunk => data += chunk);
      response.on('end', () => resolve(data));
    }).on('error', error => reject(new Error(error)));
  });
}

function extractVersionInfo(json) {
  return JSON.parse(json).map(({ version, npm = null }) => {
    return {
      nodejs: version.replace(/^v/, ''),
      npm
    };
  });
}

(async function logVersionInfo() {
  try {
    const json = await requestVersionInfo(ENDPOINT);
    const versionInfo = extractVersionInfo(json);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(versionInfo, null, 2));

  } catch ({ message }) {
    console.error(message);
  }
})();
```

Running the following command:

```sh
node ./path/to/get-versions.js
```

Will print something like the following to your console:

> ```json
> [
>   {
>     "nodejs": "14.2.0",
>     "npm": "6.14.4"
>   },
>   {
>     "nodejs": "14.1.0",
>     "npm": "6.14.4"
>   },
>   {
>     "nodejs": "14.0.0",
>     "npm": "6.14.4"
>   },
>   {
>     "nodejs": "13.14.0",
>     "npm": "6.14.4"
>   },
>   ...
> ]
> ```

It lists each version of Node.js and its respective NPM version.

Answer (score 37):

here is the list :

Node >>  10.6.0 
npm >> 6.1.0

node >> 9.0.0
npm >>  5.5.1

https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Answer (score 2):

You could also do something like this from a shell script (if you have curl and jq installed)...

```
# Get NPM version by Node Version
curl -s "https://nodejs.org/dist/index.json" | jq -r ".[] | select(.version == \"v18.16.0\") | .npm"
```