# How to concat two called endpoints to one string and print it in console

Tags: javascript, endpoint

My function has to call two endpoints and concat them in one string at the same time. My code is simply a function that is getting two endpoints at the same time and print it in console.
But the same function has to concat them to one string.
I tried to create separated variables contains each call and then simply concat them, but the result hadn't been any different.
I read about it for couple of hours, and I see no, even the smallest tip anywhere.
EDIT: Please mind that each endpoint is an actual array.

```
    function endpointsToOneString() {
        const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=json';
        Http.open("GET", url);
        Http.send();

        Http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log(Http.responseText)
            }
        }


        const HttpTwo = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const urlTwo = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=json';
        HttpTwo.open("GET", urlTwo);
        HttpTwo.send();

        HttpTwo.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                console.log(Http.responseText)
            }
        }
    }

    endpointsToOneString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should use `Promise` feature of `javascript`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30008115/4673558) you can learn how to promisify your native XHR. Morever, [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) you can find about promise chaining.
I have just added `Promise` in your code but it needs to be refactored.

**Update**: From comment, you want your response texts as a plain string. But we are actually getting a JSON array as response. So, we need to parse it using `JSON.parse()` function to make it an array object. Then we need to use `.join()` method to join all element of the array into a string. See the code below:

```js
function endpointsToOneString() {
    var requestOne = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=json';
        Http.open("GET", url);
        Http.onload = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
            resolve(Http.response);
        } else {
            reject({
            status: this.status,
            statusText: Http.statusText
            });
        }
        };
        Http.onerror = function () {
        reject({
            status: this.status,
            statusText: Http.statusText
        });
        };
        Http.send();
    });

    var requestTwo = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        const HttpTwo = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const urlTwo = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=json';
        HttpTwo.open("GET", urlTwo);
        HttpTwo.onload = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
            resolve(HttpTwo.response);
        } else {
            reject({
            status: this.status,
            statusText: HttpTwo.statusText
            });
        }
        };
        HttpTwo.onerror = function () {
        reject({
            status: this.status,
            statusText: HttpTwo.statusText
        });
        };
        HttpTwo.send();
    });


    Promise.all([
        requestOne,
        requestTwo
    ]).then(function(result){
     var response = JSON.parse(result[0]).join();
      response += JSON.parse(result[1]).join();
      console.log(response);
    });
}
endpointsToOneString();
```

Comment: I used promises like this (with a little help from my friend).  Those endpoints are an arrays. I need to concat them and join. I returns undefined to me...
https://jsfiddle.net/up7fm4ob/

Comment: @IzaAdamska I have edited my answer. Can you please check current version? However, I have formatted my code according to your format. [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u672x9da/). It's working!

Comment: I still see two arrays next to each other - isn't there a solution to have an one actual STRING from those two arrays endpoints? Like... basicaly to manipulate arrays we use concat() and join() method... can't we use it somehow?

Comment: @IzaAdamska I have updated my answer. Please check it now.

Comment: This is the result I wanted to achieve. I believe I do not understand this code in all of its shape, but - this is my recruitment task for my first job - I learn javascript only for few months. Now I will study this code to make sure I will be able to use it for the future. Thank you a lot for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to concat the result of two parallel requests. In that case you can use a library like axios. From their [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios)

```
function getUserAccount() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345');
}

function getUserPermissions() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345/permissions');
}

axios.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // Both requests are now complete
  }));
```

So for your example:

```
function getEndpoint1() {
  return axios.get('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=json');
}

function getEndpoint2() {
  return axios.get('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=json');
}

axios.all([getEndpoint1(), getEndpont2()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (resp1, resp2) {
    // Both requests are now complete
     console.log(resp1 + resp2)
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

try to have a look on the Promise.all method:
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008114/how-do-i-promisify-native-xhr) you should wrap your XHR in a Promise and then handle resolving of all function call. In this way you can access endpoint results in order.

Here's a working fiddle:

```
function makeRequest(method, url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        reject({
          status: this.status,
          statusText: xhr.statusText
        });
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      reject({
        status: this.status,
        statusText: xhr.statusText
      });
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
}

let url1 = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=json';
let url2 = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=json'
Promise.all([makeRequest('GET', url1), makeRequest('GET', url2)])
.then(values => {
  debugger;
  console.log(values);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lbrutti/octys8k2/6/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than immediately printing them, save them to local variables, then print them at the end:

```
function endpointsToOneString() {
    let response;          // this line here declares the local variable
    results = 0;           // counts results, successful or not
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=json';
    Http.open("GET", url);
    Http.send();

    Http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            response = Http.responseText;   //save one string
        }
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            results++;
        }
    }


    const HttpTwo = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const urlTwo = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=json';
    HttpTwo.open("GET", urlTwo);
    HttpTwo.send();

    HttpTwo.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            response += HttpTwo.responseText // save the other string
        }
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            results++;
        }
    }

    while(results < 2) {}  //loops until both requests finish, successful or not
    console.log(response); //print total string
}

endpointsToOneString();
```

Also, `HttpTwo`'s `onreadystatechange` function is calling for `Http.responseText`, rather than `HttpTwo.responseText`. Fix that as well for best results.

**EDIT:** Thanks for the tip, Jhon Pedroza!

**EDIT:** Noah B has pointed out that the above is dirty and inefficient. They are entirely correct. Better version based on their suggestion, credit to them:

```
function endpointsToOneString() {
    let response1 = '', response2 = ''; // this line declares the local variables
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=json';
    Http.open("GET", url);
    Http.send();

    Http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            response1 = Http.responseText;   //save one string
            checkResults(response1, response2);
        }
    }


    const HttpTwo = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const urlTwo = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=json';
    HttpTwo.open("GET", urlTwo);
    HttpTwo.send();

    HttpTwo.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            response2 = HttpTwo.responseText; // save the other string
            checkResults(response1, response2);
        }
    }
}

function checkResults(r1, r2) {
    if (r1 != '' && r2 != '') {
        console.log(r1 + r2);
    }
}

endpointsToOneString();
```

Comment: that won't work if the requests don't finish before the console.log is executed

Comment: That's super inefficient.  Instead of looping until both responses are done, save each response to a separate variable and call a function that will print the responses if both variables have content.

Comment: Check the value of results once, in each callback, don't have a loop!

Answer (score 0):

```
function endpointsToOneString() {
    var response;
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=json';
    Http.open("GET", url);
    Http.send();

    Http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            response = this.responseText;
            HttpTwo.open("GET", urlTwo);
            HttpTwo.send();
        }
    }


    const HttpTwo = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const urlTwo = 'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=3&start-with-lorem=1&format=json';

    HttpTwo.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           response += this.responseText; 
           console.log(response);
        }
    }
}

endpointsToOneString();
```

check this out. there's just minimal editing to your code.

Comment: What if HttpTwo finishes before Http?

Comment: @MaclainAnderson got you..! still we can avoid "Promise" as someone stated above. check the edited code, that should work perfectly.

Comment: Thing is, these endpoints are actual arrays - please check those url's...
I was trying promises, but it returns to me undefined... https://jsfiddle.net/up7fm4ob/

Comment: @IzaAdamska what you're trying to achieve? Do you want these endpoints to be stored in array?

Comment: @IzaAdamska btw, for the fiddle you sent, the error in it is within the ajax requests. The onreadystatechange is not assigned with a correct function. Try the traditional way, e.g: Http.onreadystatechange = function() { if(this.readyState==4 && this.status == 200) { resolve(this.responseText); } }

Answer (score 0):

Is it obligatory for you to use XMLHttpRequest? If not, u had better use fetch, because it returns Promise and with Promise it would be much simpler.

Comment: No, it is not, but I am a very begginer, I was searching for solutions in the internet to built this code, this way was the only one to be completely understood for me.
I know about fetch method, but I still know not enough to use it wisely.