# Javascript use value of variable after function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, xmlhttprequest

```js
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
let data;

request.open('POST', "https://example.page");

request.setRequestHeader(not important);
request.setRequestHeader(not important);
request.setRequestHeader(not important);

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    data = this.responseText;
  }
};

const body = '{some values}';
request.send(body);

var test = data; <-- test ends up being undefined
```

How can I use the value I get from the response text outside the function? I tried to do this with a callback function, but that didn't really work out.

I'm kinda new to javascript and I would really appreciate some help :)

Comment: this is async. you have to lean about promises

Comment: do you have a helpful website for me where I can give it a try?

Comment: You are supposed to make a search... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30008114/how-do-i-promisify-native-xhr